# Angular Material: How to set Sidenav/Drawer to be open by default?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am using the Angular Material [`Sidenav`](https://material.angular.io/components/sidenav/overview) component.

When I serve the webpage, the sidebar does not appear (first image).

However, when I resize the browser for a while, the `Sidenav` eventually appears (second image with the hamburger icon), which is the desired state.

Why is this? Is there a way to make it appear by default?

[image: Sidenav hidden]

---

[image: Sidenav visible]

Comment: <mat-drawer #drawer class="example-sidenav" mode="side" opened="true"> solves the issue

Comment: Try what Biswajit has suggested and if you need more help , provide some code

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Per the Angular Material documentation, the `MatDrawer`/`MatSidenav` opened state may be controlled using the property `opened` as well as the method `open()`.

> #### [MatSidenav extends MatDrawer](https://material.angular.io/components/sidenav/api#MatSidenav)
>
> Selector: mat-sidenav
> Exported as: matSidenav
>
> **Properties**
> `@Input() opened: boolean` - Whether the drawer is opened. We overload this because we trigger an event when it starts or end.
>
> **Methods**
> `open` - Open the drawer.

### Example

```js
<mat-sidenav-container class="example-container">
  <mat-sidenav #sidenav mode="side" opened="true">
    Sidenav content
  </mat-sidenav>

  <mat-sidenav-content>
    <p>The content.</p>
  </mat-sidenav-content>
</mat-sidenav-container>
```

See the official [**Angular Material Sidenav Examples**](https://material.angular.io/components/sidenav/examples).

Answer (score 0):

I noticed this on the default angular material schematic for the sidebar.  For some reason the `BreakpointObserver` as async didn't seem to work right away for the nav open button.  I used `breakpointObserver.isMatched()` instead of `breakpointObserver.observe()`

In component

```
get isHandset(): boolean {
  return this.breakpointObserver.isMatched(Breakpoints.Handset);
}
```